# if condition in protractor not working correctly (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am first getting total number of li elements within ul like this.

```
var dropElementLength = dropdown_ul.all(by.tagName('li')).count();
```

Now dropElementLength is having 4. if test this variable with if condition like so.

```
 if(dropElementLength == 4) {
    expect(dropElementLength).toEqual(34);
 } else {
    expect(dropElementLength).toEqual(634);
 }
```

The error is 'Expected 4 to equal 634', where as error should 'Expected 4 to equal 34'. But if condition should gets true as dropElementLength is equal to 4.

Why if condition is not getting true?

Comment: debug your code in developer tools. and put breakpoint at if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dropElementLength` returns a promise not a bool.

Use chai-as-promised:
`expect(dropdown_ul.all(by.tagName('li')).count()).to.eventually.equals(34);`

Answer (score 0):

After @Kacper comment, I resolved my problem by writing this code.

```
dropElementLength.then(function (value) {
     if (value === 4) {
          expect(value).toEqual(34);
     } else {
          expect(value).toEqual(634);
     }
})
```